# Efficient Way to draw many individual pixels to a screen in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm currently working on something in C++ using SDL2 that requires being able to draw a lot of individual pixels with specific color values to the screen every update. I'm using SDL_RenderDrawPoint just to make sure my program works but I'm sure the performance on that is terrible. From a cursory search it seems like using a texture that is the size of my window would be fastest by using SDL_UpdateTexture and updating it with a vector of pixels with my desired pixel values with a default of {0,0,0,0} RGBA value for any pixel not changed.

However every attempt I've had at writing it fails and I'm not sure where my misunderstandings lie. This is my current code that attempts to draw a specific RGBA color value to a specific x,y coordinate in my texture. I assume the part of the buffer I'm accessing using my x,y values is incorrect but I'm unsure how to make it correct if so.

Any help is appreciated including suggestions on how to efficiently do this without a texture if there's a better way.

```
SDL_Texture* windowTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(render, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, screenWidth, screenHeight);

unsigned int* lockedPixels = nullptr;
std::vector<int> pixels(screenHeight*screenWidth*4, 0);
int pitch = 0;

int start = (y * screenWidth + x) * 4;
pixels[start + 0] = B;
pixels[start + 1] = G;
pixels[start + 2] = R;
pixels[start + 3] = A;

SDL_UpdateTexture(windowTexture, nullptr, pixels.data(), screenWidth * 4);
```

Comment: If the pixels are independent, you might want to switch to GL and write a fragment shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pixel format `RGBA8888` means that each pixel is a 32 bit element with each channel (i.e. red, green, blue or alpha) taking up 8 bits, in that order.

You may want to declare `pixels` as containing the type "32 bit unsigned integer". An `unsigned int` is typically 32 bits, but it may also be larger.

```cpp
std::vector<Uint32> pixels(screenHeight*screenWidth, 0); // Note: no *4
```

The individual R, G, B, A values (which should each be 8 bit unsigned integers) can be combined into one pixel by using shifts and bit-wise ORs:

```cpp
int start = y * screenWidth + x; // Note: no *4
pixels[start] = (R << 24U) | (G << 16U) | (B << 8U) | A;
```

Lastly, you may want to *not* hardcode the last parameter of `SDL_UpdateTexture` (i.e. pitch). Instead, use `screenWidth * sizeof(Uint32)`.

The implementation above is basically a direct implementation of "RGBA8888" and allows you to access individual pixels.
Alternatively, you could also declare an array of four times the size containing 8 bit unsigned integers. Then, the first four indices would correspond to the R, G, B, A values of the first pixel, the next four indices would correspond to the R, G, B, A values of the second pixel, etc.
Which one is faster would depend on the exact system and use-case (whether the most common operations are on pixels or individual channels).

PS. Instead of `Uint32` you could also use C++'s own `std::uint32_t` from the `cstdlib` header.

Comment: _'the `std::uint32_t` type is "optional"'_ -- right, so why not use SDL's `Uint32` type?

Comment: Could I use this same approach if I were to write directly to the texture buffer given from SDL_LockTexture()? I originally used the vector in order to reset the texture every frame but I'm fairly certain my renderer is already doing that so it seems redundant now.

Comment: Looks like a mostly meaningless correction to me. I can't imagine a scenario where `uint32_t` is missing but SDL somehow magically procures a 32-bit type. `std::uint32_t` should be used because it's the standard type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree that it's only cosmetic and in some sense only a stylistic choice. Shouldn't SDL's types be preferred in an SDL context?

Comment: Meh. It's up to the programmer, but if you use 10 libraries with each having its own `uint32_t` replacements, what will you do?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Use a compile-time assert checking that all these types are 32 bits, and then use `std::uint32_t` anyway :)

Comment: @Trey Yes, I don't see why not. This is how SDL2 expects the data to be laid out. It should be reasonably fast as well. If you could tell us what the underlying problem is you're trying to solve, then we may be able to provide more specific help. What is the algorithm that produces the pixel data? Is OpenGL an option? Parallelism? Hardware restrictions? Etc.

Comment: @Yun It's currently being used to simulate a 3d engine. I have a struct that I am grabbing my intended color from (currently formatted to an SDL_Color) and then using an x,y coordinate to determine what pixel in my window I am changing and how, the problem (I think) is properly using that x,y value to write to the texture in the correct place and with the correct color formatting. Other approaches may work but I have a feeling understanding how sdl2 does it will help even if I change libraries down the line.

Comment: @Yun I was able to get it to work properly, it was really hard to get a clear answer on the correct format to input data to the buffer but yours worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, use SDL_MapRGB or SDL_MapRGBA to calculate the value for you, using any format.

```
SDL_PixelFormat* format = SDL_AllocFormat(SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat(window));
...
Uint32 color = SDL_MapRGBA(format, R, G, B, A);
...
SDL_FreeFormat(format);
```